# How to get export shapefile from spatialite database in android

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite, gis, spatialite

I'm working on a Mobile GIS android app. I want to get export [ESRI Shapefiles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shapefile) from my [Spatialite](https://www.gaia-gis.it/gaia-sins/index.html) database when the user is offline. how can i do this? Is there any library which can help me?

Answer (score 1):

In `spatialite.h` you can find this function:

```
SPATIALITE_DECLARE int dump_shapefile (sqlite3 * sqlite, char *table,
                   char *column, char *shp_path,
                   char *charset, char *geom_type,
                   int verbose, int *rows,
                   char *err_msg);
```

which is exactly what you are looking for.

However, you have to find an Android wrapper that supports that function (it may not be available). Another method is using [GDAL for Android](https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/BuildingForAndroid) with spatialite driver to convert data to Shapefile: see how they did it in [this utility](https://github.com/FUNCATE/geotools-android/blob/e9a4f649052657a509b5b435500aed29fce3eef9/spike/mauro/ogr/src/test/java/org/geotools/data/ogr/DumpShapefile.java) included in geotools-android.

Comment: thank u very much. but how can i use that in android with android ndk. can u explain more.

Comment: I don't know how i should use ur answer.

Comment: i'm trying to use geotools in android but this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50323013/how-to-install-geotools-by-gradle-in-android-studio-3-1-2) says it's not possible. Can u show me a document to use geotools on android? thank u

Comment: You don't need GeoTools, I was just referencing an utility that does what you want. You just need [GDAL for Android](https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/BuildingForAndroid)

Comment: I was trying to do that but i faced problems u can see my errors.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50155150/ndk-build-undefined-reference-errror

Comment: I have a problem to building gdal on android